# Can't display exploding_boxplot in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, boxplot

I have recently discovered the package `explodingboxplotR` (Cf. [Github](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/explodingboxplotR)) using `D3.js` template. I have this dummy example with `iris` data to validate that it works :

```
library(explodingboxplotR)
data(iris)
exploding_boxplot(
    data.frame(
        rowname = rownames(iris),
        iris,
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    ),
    y = "Sepal.Length",
    group = "Species",
    color = "Species",
    label = "Species"
)
```

Now, I would like to integrate it in a very simple `Shiny` server. From `?exploding_boxplotOutput` :

> Description:
>
> ```
>  Output and render functions for using exploding_boxplot within
>  Shiny applications and interactive Rmd documents.
> ```
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
>  exploding_boxplotOutput(outputId, width = "100%", height = "400px")
>
>  renderExploding_boxplot(expr, env = parent.frame(), quoted = FALSE)
> ```
>
> Arguments:
>
> ```
> outputId: output variable to read from
>
> width, height: Must be a valid CSS unit (like \code'100%',
>       \code'400px', \code'auto') or a number, which will be coerced
>       to a string and have \code'px' appended.
>
>     expr: An expression that generates a exploding_boxplot
>
>      env: The environment in which to evaluate \codeexpr.
>
>   quoted: Is \codeexpr a quoted expression (with \codequote())? 
>         This is useful if you want to save an expression in a variable.
> ```

Looks pretty simple. So I set up this dummy example :

```
library(shiny)
library(explodingboxplotR)

# ui.R
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Exploding Boxplot Test"),
    mainPanel(
        exploding_boxplotOutput("box")
    )
  )
)

# server.R
data(iris)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    output$box <- renderExploding_boxplot({
        print("ping")
        exploding_boxplot(
            data.frame(
                rowname = rownames(iris),
                iris,
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE
            ),
            y = "Sepal.Length",
            group = "Species",
            color = "Species",
            label = "Species"
        )
    })
})
```

Unfortunately, as you started to expect, when I run the server, I get a blank page (with just the title; note that the `boxplot` component appears in the `html` source). You might have noted the `print("ping")` in the server code. Even this one doesn't appear in my `R` console.

I have no lead here. Does anyone have a clue of what I am missing ?

Comment: Problem solved after an update of the library.
Cf. https://github.com/timelyportfolio/explodingboxplotR/issues/4

Comment: Can you provide an answer and accept it so future users can reference it, thanks

Comment: There is no answer, actually. My code now works «as is» because the package owner fixed it. Should I delete my question ?